# How to check if optionbutton is selected for the group and store the value of the selected button for additional calculation in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

This is the first time I've done something this complicated in UserForms using VBA. I'm not sure if this is even the correct way to do this or not.

**The layout of the form**

- The form as a MultiPage with 5 pages.
- Each Page has 5 survey questions with 4 option buttons per question (Low, Medium, High, Don't know)
- 4 option buttons per question are grouped
- Low option button should have a value of 1, Medium 3, and High 5. Don't know should be 0 but if more
- Then values from these option buttons are averaged for each page. e.g. Page 1 has 5 questions, the user selects 1. Low, 2. Low, 3. Medium, 4. Don't know, 5. High. Then the average for this page should be 2. And this average is the only one I care about and needs to be save in a sheet range (which I can do later). I don't need to store other responses.

Because the pages in the Multipage can change in the future, I created a loop to create the page dynamically based on items added in the table in a separate sheet.

Also, because questions can be added or removed for each page, I also created the labels for the question and radio buttons using the loop.

**What I don't know how to do next**

The layout is complete and works. What I need to do now is the following:

1. Make the option buttons mandatory, i.e. the user must select one option button per group.
2. Get the value of the option buttons for each group and calculate the average for each page

I don't know yet how to get the value of the option button when it's used in the loop. I just learnt that VBA is an event driven program, so now I'm concerned whether I can salvage the time and effort I put in creating the form using loop the following way.

In this case, I also tried to create a dictionary, store the values. But I need to store this in a collection?

```
Private Sub CreateAssessmentForm()
    
    
    'Range variable for data from table
    Dim rngTable As Range
    Dim itemTable As Range
    
    'UI forms and multipage
    'Dim multiPage As MSForms.multiPage
    
    'Labels
    Dim itemLblBackground As Object
    Dim itemLbl As Object
    
    Dim lowRatingLabelBg As Object
    Dim medRatingLabelBg As Object
    Dim highRatingLabelBg As Object
    Dim unknownRatingLabelBg As Object
    
    Dim lowRatingLabel As Object
    Dim medRatingLabel As Object
    Dim highRatingLabel As Object
    Dim unknownRatingLabel As Object
    
    'Misc
    Dim lblName As String
    Dim lblBackground As String
    
    Dim JobGrade As Integer
    Dim itemTopPosition As Integer
    Dim altBgClr As Long
    
    'Leader Role table ID to keep track of for the Multipage tabs
    Dim activeLeaderRoleId As String
    
    
    'Radio buttons
    Dim lowRadioButton As MSForms.OptionButton
    Dim medRadioButton As MSForms.OptionButton
    Dim highRadioButton As MSForms.OptionButton
    Dim unknownRadioButton As MSForms.OptionButton
        
        
    Set RadioDictionary = New Dictionary

    
    '================================================================
    
    Me.drName = Sheets("var").Range("Y2").Value
    
    'Declaration
    JobGrade = Sheets("var").Range("z2").Value

    Me.dateLabel.Caption = DateValue(Now)

    Me.ManagerView_SubmitAssessment.Enabled = True
            
    
            
    'Define source range, referring to the table data range
    Set rngTable = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("LeaderRoles2").Range("leaderRoleTable2")
    Set itemTable = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Items").Range("itemTable")
    

    'Create a tabbed multipage to add the leader role information
    Set multiPage = AssessmentForm.DriverTabs
    multiPage.Font.Bold = False
    multiPage.Font.Name = "Verdana"
    multiPage.Font.Size = 9
    multiPage.Style = fmSpecialEffectFlat
    multiPage.ForeColor = RGB(0, 40, 85)

    
    'Total page counts that may already exist
    PageCount = multiPage.Pages.Count
    
    
    Dim itemLabelWidth As Integer
    itemLabelWidth = 325
    
    'rngTable rows have different count than rngTable.Count if multiple columns are selected
    For i = 1 To rngTable.Rows.Count
        itemTopPosition = (multiPage.Height - (32 * 5)) / 2
        'get leader role id
        activeLeaderRoleId = rngTable.Item(i, 1).Value

        If (i <= PageCount) = True Then
            multiPage.Pages(i - 1).Caption = rngTable.Item(i, 2).Value
        Else
            multiPage.Pages.Add
            Me.DriverTabs.Pages(i - 1).Name = "Page" & i
            Me.DriverTabs.Pages(i - 1).Caption = rngTable.Item(i, 2).Value
            
        End If
        
        'Tab height
        multiPage.TabFixedHeight = 25
        
        lblName = "lr" & i & "Item" & j
        lblBackground = "lblBkgrnd" & i & j
        
        
        
        'Multipage page background
        With multiPage.Pages(i - 1).Controls.Add("Forms.Label.1")
                                            .BackColor = RGB(255, 255, 255)
                                            .Width = multiPage.Width
                                            .Height = multiPage.Height
                                            .Top = 0
                                            .Left = 0
        End With
        
                
        
        'For alternating the background in the item labels
        Dim k As Integer
        k = 1
        
        'Loop through item table to add items to the multipage page
        For j = 1 To itemTable.Rows.Count
            
            
            If itemTable.Item(j, 2).Value = activeLeaderRoleId And itemTable.Item(j, 3) = JobGrade Then
                
                
                
                Set itemLblBackground = multiPage.Pages(i - 1).Controls.Add("Forms.Label.1", lblBackground)
                Set itemLbl = multiPage.Pages(i - 1).Controls.Add("Forms.Label.1", lblName)
                
                altBgClr = RGB(250, 250, 250)
                
                If (k Mod 2 = 0) Then altBgClr = RGB(255, 255, 255)

                'Alternate background
                With itemLblBackground
                        .Caption = ""
                        .BorderStyle = fmBorderStyleNone
                        .BackColor = altBgClr
                        .Left = 0
                        .Width = multiPage.Width
                        .Height = 35
                        .Top = itemTopPosition
                        
                End With
                
               
                'display items
                With itemLbl
                        .Caption = itemTable.Item(j, 4).Value
                        .BackStyle = fmBackStyleTransparent
                        .Font.Name = "Verdana"
                        .AutoSize = True
                        .Font.Size = 10
                        .Left = 6
                        .Width = itemLabelWidth
                        .Height = 30
                        .Top = (itemLblBackground.Top + (itemLblBackground.Height - itemLbl.Height) / 2) 'itemLblBackground.Top
                End With
                
         
         
                '==============================================================================================================
                '
                ' LOW RADIO BUTTON
                '
                '==============================================================================================================
                
                'Low radio button
                Dim lowLabelName As String
                Dim medLabelName As String
                Dim highLabelName As String
                Dim unknownLabelName As String
                
                lowLabelName = "lowRadioGroup" & i & "_" & j
                medLabelName = "medRadioGroup" & i & "_" & j
                highLabelName = "highRadioGroup" & i & "_" & j
                unknownLabelName = "unknownRadioGroup" & i & "_" & j
                
                
                Set lowRadioButton = multiPage.Pages(i - 1).Controls.Add("Forms.OptionButton.1", lowLabelName)
                
                With lowRadioButton
                    .Width = 20
                    .BackStyle = fmBackStyleTransparent
                    .Left = itemLabelWidth + 40
                    .Top = (itemLblBackground.Top + (itemLblBackground.Height - itemLbl.Height) / 2)
                    .GroupName = "RatingButton" & j
                    
                    
                End With
                
                RadioDictionary("Name") = lowLabelName
                RadioDictionary("GroupName") = lowRadioButton.GroupName
                RadioDictionary("Value") = lowRadioButton.Value
                
                
                '==============================================================================================================
                '
                ' MEDIUM RADIO BUTTON
                '
                '==============================================================================================================
                Set medRadioButton = multiPage.Pages(i - 1).Controls.Add("Forms.OptionButton.1", medLabelName)
                
                With medRadioButton
                    .Width = 20
                    .BackStyle = fmBackStyleTransparent
                    .Left = lowRadioButton.Left + lowRadioButton.Width + 40
                    .Top = (itemLblBackground.Top + (itemLblBackground.Height - itemLbl.Height) / 2)
                    .GroupName = "RatingButton" & j
                    
                
                
                End With
                
                RadioDictionary("Name") = medLabelName
                RadioDictionary("GroupName") = medRadioButton.GroupName
                RadioDictionary("Value") = medRadioButton.Value

                '==============================================================================================================
                '
                ' HIGH RADIO BUTTON
                '
                '==============================================================================================================
                Set highRadioButton = multiPage.Pages(i - 1).Controls.Add("Forms.OptionButton.1", highLabelName)
                
                With highRadioButton
                    .Width = 20
                    .BackStyle = fmBackStyleTransparent
                    .Left = medRadioButton.Left + medRadioButton.Width + 40
                    .Top = (itemLblBackground.Top + (itemLblBackground.Height - itemLbl.Height) / 2)
                    .GroupName = "RatingButton" & j
                    
                
                End With
                
                RadioDictionary("Name") = highLabelName
                RadioDictionary("GroupName") = highRadioButton.GroupName
                RadioDictionary("Value") = highRadioButton.Value

                                
                '==============================================================================================================
                '
                ' DON'T KNOW RADIO BUTTON
                '
                '==============================================================================================================
                Set unknownRadioButton = multiPage.Pages(i - 1).Controls.Add("Forms.OptionButton.1", unknownLabelName)

                With unknownRadioButton
                    .Width = 22
                    .BackStyle = fmBackStyleTransparent
                    .Left = highRadioButton.Left + highRadioButton.Width + 45
                    .Top = (itemLblBackground.Top + (itemLblBackground.Height - itemLbl.Height) / 2)
                    .GroupName = "RatingButton" & j
                    

                End With
                
                RadioDictionary("Name") = unknownLabelName
                RadioDictionary("GroupName") = unknownRadioButton.GroupName
                RadioDictionary("Value") = unknownRadioButton.Value

                
                
                itemTopPosition = itemTopPosition + itemLblBackground.Height
                                
                k = k + 1
            End If
            
        Next j 'End item table range
        
        
        
        '==============================================================================================================
        '
        ' DISPLAY RATING OPTIONS AND LINE BOUNDARIES
        '
        '==============================================================================================================
        
        
        'Adding a line in the headers
        With multiPage.Pages(i - 1).Controls.Add("Forms.Label.1")
                                .Width = multiPage.Width - 10
                                .Height = 1
                                .Top = multiPage.TabFixedHeight + 16
                                .Left = multiPage.Left - 10

        End With
        
        
        'Adding a line between items and control
        With multiPage.Pages(i - 1).Controls.Add("Forms.Label.1")
                                .Width = 1
                                .Height = multiPage.Height - multiPage.TabFixedHeight
                                .Top = 10
                                .Left = itemLabelWidth + 10

        End With
        
        
        '==============================================================================================================
        '
        ' LOW
        '
        '==============================================================================================================
        
        Set lowRatingLabelBg = multiPage.Pages(i - 1).Controls.Add("Forms.Label.1")
        
        'Low rating instruction background
        With lowRatingLabelBg
                .BackColor = RGB(244, 67, 54)
                .Left = itemLabelWidth + 20
                .Top = 12
                .Width = 50
                .Height = 25
        End With
        
        'Low rating instruction label
        Set lowRatingLabel = multiPage.Pages(i - 1).Controls.Add("Forms.Label.1")
        
        With lowRatingLabel
                .Caption = "LOW"
                .BackColor = RGB(244, 67, 54)
                .Width = 24
                .Height = 12
                .Left = lowRatingLabelBg.Left + (lowRatingLabelBg.Width - lowRatingLabel.Width) / 2
                .Top = lowRatingLabelBg.Top + (lowRatingLabelBg.Height - lowRatingLabel.Height) / 2
                .ForeColor = RGB(255, 255, 255)
        End With
        
        
        
        'Adding a line between items and control
        With multiPage.Pages(i - 1).Controls.Add("Forms.Label.1")
                                .Width = 1
                                .Height = multiPage.Height - multiPage.TabFixedHeight
                                .Top = 10
                                .Left = lowRatingLabelBg.Width + lowRatingLabelBg.Left + 5

        End With
        
        
        
        '==============================================================================================================
        '
        ' MEDIUM
        '
        '==============================================================================================================
        
        Set medRatingLabelBg = multiPage.Pages(i - 1).Controls.Add("Forms.Label.1")
        
        
        'Med rating instruction
        With medRatingLabelBg
                .BackColor = RGB(255, 193, 7)
                .Left = lowRatingLabelBg.Left + lowRatingLabelBg.Width + 10
                .Top = 12
                .Width = 50
                .Height = 25
        End With


        'Low rating instruction label
        Set medRatingLabel = multiPage.Pages(i - 1).Controls.Add("Forms.Label.1")
        
        With medRatingLabel
                .Caption = "MEDIUM"
                .BackStyle = fmBackStyleTransparent
                .Width = 42
                .Height = 12
                .Left = medRatingLabelBg.Left + (medRatingLabelBg.Width - medRatingLabel.Width) / 2
                .Top = medRatingLabelBg.Top + (medRatingLabelBg.Height - medRatingLabel.Height) / 2
                .ForeColor = RGB(9, 9, 9)
        End With
        


        'Adding a line between items and control
        With multiPage.Pages(i - 1).Controls.Add("Forms.Label.1")
                                .Width = 1
                                .Height = multiPage.Height - multiPage.TabFixedHeight
                                .Top = 10
                                .Left = medRatingLabelBg.Width + medRatingLabelBg.Left + 5

        End With
        
        '==============================================================================================================
        '
        ' HIGH
        '
        '==============================================================================================================

        Set highRatingLabelBg = multiPage.Pages(i - 1).Controls.Add("Forms.Label.1")
        
        'Med rating instruction
        With highRatingLabelBg
                .BackColor = RGB(46, 125, 50)
                .Left = medRatingLabelBg.Left + medRatingLabelBg.Width + 10
                .Top = 12
                .Width = 50
                .Height = 25
        End With
        
        
        Set highRatingLabel = multiPage.Pages(i - 1).Controls.Add("Forms.Label.1")
        
        With highRatingLabel
                .Caption = "HIGH"
                .BackStyle = fmBackStyleTransparent
                .Width = 26
                .Height = 12
                .Left = highRatingLabelBg.Left + (highRatingLabelBg.Width - highRatingLabel.Width) / 2
                .Top = highRatingLabelBg.Top + (highRatingLabelBg.Height - highRatingLabel.Height) / 2
                .ForeColor = RGB(255, 255, 255)
        End With
        
        'Adding a line between items and control
        With multiPage.Pages(i - 1).Controls.Add("Forms.Label.1")
                                .Width = 1
                                .Height = multiPage.Height - multiPage.TabFixedHeight
                                .Top = 10
                                .Left = highRatingLabelBg.Width + highRatingLabelBg.Left + 5

        End With
        
        
        '==============================================================================================================
        '
        ' Don't Know
        '
        '==============================================================================================================

        Set unknownRatingLabelBg = multiPage.Pages(i - 1).Controls.Add("Forms.Label.1")

        'Dont know rating instruction
        With unknownRatingLabelBg
                .BackColor = RGB(148, 176, 182)
                .Left = highRatingLabelBg.Left + highRatingLabelBg.Width + 10
                .Top = 12
                .Width = 65
                .Height = 25
        End With


        Set unknownRatingLabel = multiPage.Pages(i - 1).Controls.Add("Forms.Label.1")

        With unknownRatingLabel
                .Caption = "DON'T KNOW"
                .BackStyle = fmBackStyleTransparent
                .Width = 80
                .Height = 12
                .Left = unknownRatingLabelBg.Left + 9 + (unknownRatingLabelBg.Width - unknownRatingLabel.Width) / 2
                .Top = unknownRatingLabelBg.Top + (unknownRatingLabelBg.Height - unknownRatingLabel.Height) / 2
                .ForeColor = RGB(255, 255, 255)
        End With
        
    Next i 'End leader role table range
    
    
    'Finally, get the actual page count
    PageCount = multiPage.Pages.Count
        
End Sub
```

Comment: The code is too long to try reading it and understanding what is it about. So, do you need to `store` the values for a later use, or for Form life? If for Form life, like I (only) suppose,  you should create boolean variables relevantly named, to be `True` (in their events) when specific Option buttons are checked (and `False` the others). Even created on the fly, it is possible to create events for them. Then, it is a matter of logic evaluation of the boolean variables. In order to make the option buttons group mandatory, you can also allow the next step checking the `True` boolean variables.

Comment: Thanks for very helpful comment. Would you say having radio buttons dynamically in pages (multipage) is a bad way to do this? What would be a good design?

Comment: No, I did not suggest that. I only tries suggesting that having the option buttons manually created (of course, if possible), it is very easy to use their `Change` event in order to change values of specific `Boolean` variables. In such a case, I would say that your problem, as  I understood it, is solved. But, as I said, it is possible to create events and their code for option buttons created on the fly. But this is (much) more complicated...

Comment: Got it! That's very helpful. I'll try to find out some information on capturing the events dynamically. The issue with creating the option buttons manually is that the macro won't be scalable. I don't know how many question items are there and will be added later. That's why I thought having  dynamic one is useful. But I get your point. Thank you for your helpful suggestion.

Comment: I prepared a simple event wrapper class and a piece of code, able to add Option buttons on the fly, showing the way of updating some form boolean variables. I will post it in few minutes...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In regards of what I tried to suggest (in comments) I prepared a simple event wrapper class, which must be built in this way:

1. Insert a class module, name it `optBClass` and paste the next code inside it:

```
Option Explicit

Public WithEvents optEvent As MSForms.OptionButton
Private Sub optEvent_Change()
    If optEvent.Name = "Opt1" Then
        If optEvent.Value = True Then
            testOptCreate.boolOpt1 = True
            testOptCreate.boolOpt2 = False: testOptCreate.boolOpt3 = False
        Else
            testOptCreate.boolOpt1 = False
            testOptCreate.boolOpt2 = False: testOptCreate.boolOpt3 = False
        End If
    ElseIf optEvent.Name = "Opt2" Then
        If optEvent.Value = True Then
            testOptCreate.boolOpt2 = True
            testOptCreate.boolOpt1 = False: testOptCreate.boolOpt3 = False
        Else
            testOptCreate.boolOpt1 = False
            testOptCreate.boolOpt2 = False: testOptCreate.boolOpt3 = False
        End If
    ElseIf optEvent.Name = "Opt3" Then
        If optEvent.Value = True Then
            testOptCreate.boolOpt3 = True
            testOptCreate.boolOpt1 = False: testOptCreate.boolOpt2 = False
        Else
            testOptCreate.boolOpt1 = False
            testOptCreate.boolOpt2 = False: testOptCreate.boolOpt3 = False
        End If
    End If
        MsgBox optEvent.Name & " - " & optEvent.Value & vbCrLf & _
                "boolOpt1 = " & testOptCreate.boolOpt1 & vbCrLf & _
                "boolOpt2 = " & testOptCreate.boolOpt2 & vbCrLf & _
                "boolOpt3 = " & testOptCreate.boolOpt3
End Sub
```

2. On top of the the form (module) you want to create option buttons, on the fly (`testOptCreate` in my exammple), please create the next variable  (in the declarations part):

```
Option Explicit

Private optBColl As New Collection
Private OptionB() As New optBClass
Public boolOpt1 As Boolean, boolOpt2 As Boolean, boolOpt3 As Boolean
```

3. Create a button (`btCreateOptB`) and use this code for its Click event:

```
Private Sub btCreateOptB_Click()
 Dim optCount As Long, theOptB As control, i As Long

 optCount = 3
 ReDim OptionB(0 To optCount)
 For i = 1 To optCount

         Set theOptB = Me.Controls.aDD("Forms.OptionButton.1", "Opt" & i, True)
         With theOptB
            .height = 17
            .Caption = "Opt" & i
            .left = 50 * i
          End With

        optBColl.aDD theOptB, theOptB.Name
        Set OptionB(i).optEvent = theOptB
 Next i
End Sub
```

4. Show the form and press `btCreateOptB` button!
5. Check each newly created option buttons. When first of them is clicked, the message box being shown display the clicked option button name, its value and the boolean variables associated to the group values.

Starting from the second option button click, the message will be shown twice. One time triggered by the previous option button change (its value becomes false) and second time referring to the last option button clicked.

Please, try understanding of its logic and try to apply it on your project.
If something not clear, do not hesitate to ask, even if I believe that it should be clear enough...

You can also use a `Dictionary` to automatically create boolean variables and use it to keep all of them and check when needed. Look, please at this test `Sub`:

```
Sub testDictionaryBooleanVar()
  'it needs a reference to 'Microsoft Scripting Runtime`, 
  'or `dict` variable must be created `As Object` and create through `Set dict = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")`
  Dim it As Variant, dict As New Scripting.Dictionary, i As Long
    With dict
        For i = 1 To 10
            .Item("boolOpt" & i) = False
        Next i
    End With
    dict.Item("boolOpt2") = True: dict.Item("boolOpt5") = True
    Debug.Print Join(dict.Items, "|")
    Debug.Print dict("boolOpt2"), dict("boolOpt3")
End Sub
```

Presented this option in order to suggest a way to avoid manually creating boolean variables to be checked in the Option button Change event...